# Ansible tasks still run regardless of tags

Tags: ansible, tags, ansible-2.x

I have following playbook. If I run with --tags "decommision", only 2 tasks were triggered which is correct. But when I run the playbook with --tags "deliver", the last tasks is still running regardless of its tags being "decommission". I can't seem to figure out. My indentation is fine too.

```
tasks:
- name: Change PS 1
  command: sed -i 's/PS1=\"\[\\u\@\\h\ \\W\]/PS1=\"\[\\u\@\\H\ \\W\]/g' /etc/bashrc
  tags: deliver, update
  
- name: Update Info In CMDB 
  uri:
    url: "update url"
    method: POST
    body: {"ip_list": ["{{ ansible_host }}"]}
    body_format: json
  tags: deliver, update

- name: Remove Old Targets
  uri:
    url: "remove url"
    method: POST
    body: {"job_name": "{{ jobname }}", "host_list": ["{{ ansible_host }}"]}
    body_format: json
  tags: deliver, decommision, update

- name: Associate Host With Prometheus
  uri:
    url: "prometheus url"
    method: POST
    body: {"ip_list": [ "{{ ansible_host }}" ]}
    body_format: json
  tags: deliver 

- name: Register monitoring job
  uri:
    url: "register url"
    method: POST
    body: {"host_list": ["{{ ansible_host }}"]}
    body_format: json
  tags: deliver, update_hostname

- name: Remove Association Host With Prometheus
  uri:
    url: "remove url"
    method: POST
    body: {"ip_list": [ "{{ ansible_host }}" ]}
    body_format: json
  tags: decommision
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. There must be some reason not obvious from the code you posted. You should minimize the code and try to isolate the problem. For example, start with "debug" only in each task and try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Change PS 1
      tags: deliver, update
  
    - debug:
        msg: Update Info In CMDB
      tags: deliver, update

    - debug:
        msg: Remove Old Targets
      tags: deliver, decommision, update

    - debug:
        msg: Associate Host With Prometheus
      tags: deliver 

    - debug:
        msg: Register monitoring job
      tags: deliver, update_hostname

    - debug:
        msg: Remove Association Host With Prometheus
      tags: decommision
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --tags "deliver" | grep msg\:
  msg: Change PS 1
  msg: Update Info In CMDB
  msg: Remove Old Targets
  msg: Associate Host With Prometheus
  msg: Register monitoring job
```